# Monokai minted theme annoyingly highlighting unicode caracters

Tags: xetex, unicode, minted

I recently started using the monokai theme with `minted` which I use because it works well with XeLaTeX. I found that when using unicode characters in code they get highlighted is red. This behaviour is not to be seen in the default theme of `minted` for Python so I'm guessing that it has something to do with the monokai theme. Any ideas on how to remove the ugly highlighting?

Here's what the problem looks like (the unicode parenthesis are highlighted red):

[image: Illustration of the highlighting problem]

**Edit** Here's a minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}


\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{codeBg}{HTML}{282822}
\definecolor{textBg}{HTML}{1c1c17}

\setminted[python]{
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    bgcolor=codeBg
}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{textBg}
\color{white}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

Commençons par un exemple : vérifions que la matrice
\[A = \begin{pmatrix}3&9&-9\\2&0&0\\3&3&3\end{pmatrix}\] 
est nilpotente d'indice 3.
\begin{minted}{python}
>>> from matrix import *
>>> A = Matrix([
... [3, 9,-9],
... [2, 0, 0],
... [3, 3,-3]
... ])
>>> A**2

⎛0 0   0 ⎞
⎜6 18 -18⎟
⎝6 18 -18⎠

>>> A**3

⎛0 0 0⎞
⎜0 0 0⎟
⎝0 0 0⎠

\end{minted}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you checked your editor's setting on how parentheses are highlighted?

Comment: This is a screenshot of the pdf file. It has nothing to do with the way my editor is set up. But I look into the possibility that my pdf viewer does that.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that shows the behaviour? Maybe it is because of your PDF viewer, maybe there is a bug. It would be easier to track down, if we had a minimal working example.

Comment: I don't see a `matrix` module at https://pypi.python.org/pypi. Hence it is very time costly to try to hep you because you did not paste simply your interactive session as characters but an image.

Comment: @jfbu I didn't paste the Python session because I didn't think you would want to copy and paste it. The `matrix` module is just a custom built module, it can't be found on the internet.

Comment: The lexer doesn't know about the parenthesis pieces, and flags them with `err`, for instance `\PYG{err}{⎛}`

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the input, I don't get this highlighting without the monokai theme though which is surprising.

Comment: I get the same `\PYG{err}` if I comment out the call to the monokai style. The flag is inserted at the lexer level.

Comment: Now I get it as well on the minimal example. Previously it rendered fine (on the big original file). Anyhow, do you have a fix for this?

Comment: you can take a hint from this [sphinx issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4249), about doing some appropriate `\def\PYG@tok@err`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was pointed out in comments the Pygmentize lexers may be (depending on programming language involved) [very picky](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4225#issuecomment-343661669) about Unicode characters and may flag them as error tokens. This is inherited by the monokai style.

The real fix is to fix the lexer. Oops, I now understand correct fix to your problem. For sentimental reason, I keep my initial one. But skip to bottom for real fix.

**edit**

- I had not observed OP's code loaded all of `inputenc`, `fontenc`, *and* `fontspec` with `\setmainfont`. I have removed `inputenc` and `fontenc` loading in an edit.
- In my sentimentally kept approach the replacement text of `\PYGmonokai@tok@err` did not use correctly prefixed macro. I have fixed it too. But I don't recall now when is the `@bc` activated. (one needs to examine Pygmentize latex templates for that). Could be that `bc` is for background color` but right now I don't recall.

---

I did not immediately fing in `minted` suitable hooks from the documentation, so I decided to patch the `fancyvrb` `Verbatim` environment which is used by `minted`. I also have a bit lost out of memory the  `fancyvrb` hooks, so I did it brutally via `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%%%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% NO! fontspec loaded below
%%%% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}


\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{codeBg}{HTML}{282822}
\definecolor{textBg}{HTML}{1c1c17}

\setminted[python]{
    breaklines=true,
    encoding=utf8,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    bgcolor=codeBg
}


\makeatletter
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{Verbatim}{%
%\show\PYGmonokai@tok@err
   \def\PYGmonokai@tok@err {\def\PYGmonokai@bc##1{\strut ##1}}%
%\show\PYGmonokai@tok@err
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\pagecolor{textBg}
\color{white}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

Commençons par un exemple : vérifions que la matrice
\[A = \begin{pmatrix}3&9&-9\\2&0&0\\3&3&3\end{pmatrix}\] 
est nilpotente d'indice 3.

\begin{minted}{python}
>>> from matrix import *
>>> A = Matrix([
... [3, 9,-9],
... [2, 0, 0],
... [3, 3,-3]
... ])
>>> A**2

⎛0 0   0 ⎞
⎜6 18 -18⎟
⎝6 18 -18⎠

>>> A**3

⎛0 0 0⎞
⎜0 0 0⎟
⎝0 0 0⎠

\end{minted}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice in this context that the Pygmentize latex stylesheets have some bugs, which are inherited by minted. Here are some links to the Pygments issue tracker. (it does not look like those issues will get fixed any time soon)

- https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1409/latex-formatter-border-style-offsets
- https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1410/latex-style-should-limit-change-of-fboxsep

---

Coming back to real problem: you are using the `python` lexer for an interactive session. You should have used the `pycon` lexer.

```
$ pygmentize -L lexers | grep -C 1 py
    ANTLR With Perl Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
* antlr-python:
    ANTLR With Python Target (filenames *.G, *.g)
--
    Bro (filenames *.bro)
* bst, bst-pybtex:
    BST (filenames *.bst)
--
* cobol:
    COBOL (filenames *.cob, *.COB, *.cpy, *.CPY)
* cobolfree:
--
    Cypher (filenames *.cyp, *.cypher)
* cython, pyx, pyrex:
    Cython (filenames *.pyx, *.pxd, *.pxi)
* d-objdump:
--
    Ioke (filenames *.ik)
* ipython2, ipython:
    IPython 
* ipython3:
    IPython3 
* ipythonconsole:
    IPython console session 
--
    NSIS (filenames *.nsi, *.nsh)
* numpy:
    NumPy 
--
    Puppet (filenames *.pp)
* py3tb:
    Python 3.0 Traceback (filenames *.py3tb)
* pycon:
    Python console session 
* pypylog, pypy:
    PyPy Log (filenames *.pypylog)
* pytb:
    Python Traceback (filenames *.pytb)
* python, py, sage:
    Python (filenames *.py, *.pyw, *.sc, SConstruct, SConscript, *.tac, *.sage)
* python3, py3:
    Python 3
```

Thus here is with :

```
\begin{minted}{pycon}
>>> from matrix import *
>>> A = Matrix([
... [3, 9,-9],
... [2, 0, 0],
... [3, 3,-3]
... ])
>>> A**2

⎛0 0   0 ⎞
⎜6 18 -18⎟
⎝6 18 -18⎠

>>> A**3

⎛0 0 0⎞
⎜0 0 0⎟
⎝0 0 0⎠

\end{minted}
```

[image]

Comment: IMO it may be better to put the “correct” solution (use `pycon`, not `python`, because those characters are indeed errors in Python code) at the top of the answer, and the rest of it later (if still relevant).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR  no, leaving as is. That minted provides no easily found in its doc means for patches such as those is a problem, because it makes it hard to workaround bugs of Pygments LaTeX styles.

Comment: OK sure, but in this case there is no bug (just user error), I think? Or is there?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR no you are right, here it is only user error. But the Pygments highlighting of error tokens is buggy, and the fact that some Pygments lexers (the one for Coq language for example) emit error tokens when encountering Unicode chars despite the language syntax allowing them is another limitation. In my brief investigation I saw no quick `minted` way to workaround those things, this is why I am leaving my answer as is in case it can be recycled.

Comment: Waw. Very helpful. `pycon` seems to be the right way to solve the problem (even if the colored matrices are nice as well). Thanks for your time !